# how can split a text in textbox

Tags: c#, vb.net

guys, I have a simple question I hope you can help me.

I have a textbox(Command) and a Richtextbox(Console)

I have a command like this: Set username=Admin password=Admin1 OS=Windows

I want a split username, password, os

how can do this?

Comment: Tip: split with single space and then each item with `=`. But this is not the way to ask question here

Comment: Always tra google before coming here. Always try something and show your code and explain what isn't working before asking here!!

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I good understand you need parse text from textbox(command) to get values.

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetValues(string line) {
    string[] valuesArray = line.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Contains("=")).ToArray();
    IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var value in valuesArray) {
        string[] nameValue = value.Split('=');
        dictionary.Add(nameValue[0], nameValue[1]);
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```